# ios crash report from apple, unable to reproduce

Tags: ios, crash-log

I have the following 2 crash reports from app review team.

Report 1:

```
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             lli [743]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF9090C9-118F-4C7E-B66F-B62F7D68309B/lli.app/lli
Identifier:          com.lh.lli
Version:             2.0.3 (2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.lh.lli [656]


Date/Time:           2017-07-05 12:37:27.6939 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-07-05 12:37:21.4654 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18f33efe0 0x18dda0538 0x18f33eeb4 0x18fdd6720 0x195c48c2c 0x195c4b33c 0x195c518e4 0x18e1f69a0 0x18e2077a8 0x18e1f69a0 0x18e1fb5e8 0x18f2ed0c8 0x18f2eace4 0x18f21ada4 0x190c84074 0x1954ce058 0x100114684 0x18e22959c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339014 0x18e31a000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e403264 0x18e3fe000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e2ad9c4 0x18e24c000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018dd791b0 0x18dd78000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018dd8f5f0 0x18dd78000 + 95728
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018dd8f640 0x18dd78000 + 95808
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69b4 0x18e1f5000 + 6580
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2077a8 0x18e1f5000 + 75688
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69a0 0x18e1f5000 + 6560
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1fb5e8 0x18e1f5000 + 26088
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ed0c8 0x18f212000 + 897224
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eace4 0x18f212000 + 888036
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
13  GraphicsServices                0x0000000190c84074 0x190c78000 + 49268
14  UIKit                           0x00000001954ce058 0x195459000 + 479320
15  lli                             0x0000000100114684 0x1000bc000 + 362116
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018e22959c 0x18e225000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339a88 0x18e31a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff1a4 0x18e3fe000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339a88 0x18e31a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff1a4 0x18e3fe000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339a88 0x18e31a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff1a4 0x18e3fe000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: UIDocument File Presenting :: NSOperation 0x1744415c0 (QOS: DEFAULT)
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e3398e8 0x18e31a000 + 129256
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e20977c 0x18e1f5000 + 83836
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2098a4 0x18e1f5000 + 84132
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2074f0 0x18e1f5000 + 74992
4   UIKit                           0x0000000195c5356c 0x195459000 + 8365420
5   UIKit                           0x0000000195c535d0 0x195459000 + 8365520
6   UIKit                           0x0000000195c51524 0x195459000 + 8357156
7   Foundation                      0x000000018fee4e48 0x18fd28000 + 1822280
8   Foundation                      0x000000018fe0d814 0x18fd28000 + 940052
9   Foundation                      0x000000018fd52770 0x18fd28000 + 173936
10  Foundation                      0x000000018fd42b28 0x18fd28000 + 109352
11  Foundation                      0x000000018fe0fbb0 0x18fd28000 + 949168
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69a0 0x18e1f5000 + 6560
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e204ad4 0x18e1f5000 + 64212
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1fa2cc 0x18e1f5000 + 21196
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e206a50 0x18e1f5000 + 72272
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2067d0 0x18e1f5000 + 71632
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff100 0x18e3fe000 + 4352
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x000000018fd34d74 0x18fd28000 + 52596
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fd55b44 0x18fd28000 + 187204
7   UIKit                           0x0000000195e586a8 0x195459000 + 10483368
8   Foundation                      0x000000018fe322d8 0x18fd28000 + 1090264
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339a88 0x18e31a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff1a4 0x18e3fe000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a8f1e540 0x1a8eaa000 + 476480
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a8f44814 0x1a8eaa000 + 632852
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e338e1c 0x18e31a000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e400814 0x18e3fe000 + 10260
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018dd29ac8 0x18dd22000 + 31432
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc6f94 0x19320d000 + 10198932
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc6f08 0x19320d000 + 10198792
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc6de8 0x19320d000 + 10198504
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc7098 0x19320d000 + 10199192
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFNetwork.CustomProtocols
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fb82f50 0x18f945000 + 2350928
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa26df4 0x18f945000 + 925172
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fe322d8 0x18fd28000 + 1090264
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 11 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   AudioToolbox                    0x000000019218de00 0x1920ea000 + 671232
3   AudioToolbox                    0x000000019219205c 0x1920ea000 + 688220
4   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001924724bc 0x1920ea000 + 3703996
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   AudioToolbox                    0x000000019229e9fc 0x1920ea000 + 1788412
6   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001924724bc 0x1920ea000 + 3703996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 13 name:  Dispatch queue: UIDocument File Access
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e3398e8 0x18e31a000 + 129256
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e20977c 0x18e1f5000 + 83836
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2098a4 0x18e1f5000 + 84132
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2074f0 0x18e1f5000 + 74992
4   UIKit                           0x0000000195c5356c 0x195459000 + 8365420
5   UIKit                           0x0000000195c4d574 0x195459000 + 8340852
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69e0 0x18e1f5000 + 6624
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69a0 0x18e1f5000 + 6560
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e204ad4 0x18e1f5000 + 64212
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1fa2cc 0x18e1f5000 + 21196
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e204fa8 0x18e1f5000 + 65448
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e206a50 0x18e1f5000 + 72272
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2067d0 0x18e1f5000 + 71632
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff100 0x18e3fe000 + 4352
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 14 name:  Dispatch queue: UIDocument File Access
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e3398e8 0x18e31a000 + 129256
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e20977c 0x18e1f5000 + 83836
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2098a4 0x18e1f5000 + 84132
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2074f0 0x18e1f5000 + 74992
4   UIKit                           0x0000000195c5356c 0x195459000 + 8365420
5   UIKit                           0x0000000195c535d0 0x195459000 + 8365520
6   UIKit                           0x0000000195c490b8 0x195459000 + 8323256
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69e0 0x18e1f5000 + 6624
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1f69a0 0x18e1f5000 + 6560
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e204ad4 0x18e1f5000 + 64212
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e1fa2cc 0x18e1f5000 + 21196
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e204fa8 0x18e1f5000 + 65448
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e206a50 0x18e1f5000 + 72272
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e2067d0 0x18e1f5000 + 71632
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff100 0x18e3fe000 + 4352
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700f6db1
    x4: 0x000000018dd938a7   x5: 0x000000016fd42c20   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000002
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000016fd42690  x11: 0x0000000000000031
   x12: 0x0000020000000303  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000018ddbee2c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b4d97b40  x21: 0x000000016fd42c20  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016e15e810
   x24: 0x00000001b4d97c20  x25: 0x0000000000000003  x26: 0xffffffffffffffff  x27: 0x000000016e15e810
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016fd42b80   lr: 0x000000018e403264
    sp: 0x000000016fd42b60   pc: 0x000000018e339014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Report 2:

```
CrashReporter Key:   598ae5bd4fdca51ac5445ddcaec1fe7cde4f1078
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             lli [752]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF9090C9-118F-4C7E-B66F-B62F7D68309B/lli.app/lli
Identifier:          com.lh.lli
Version:             2.0.3 (2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.lh.lli [660]


Date/Time:           2017-07-05 12:38:25.4530 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-07-05 12:38:10.8891 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18f33efe0 0x18dda0538 0x18f33ef28 0x100236124 0x18e3fd30c 0x10006c47c 0x1000be188 0x1000bd0b0 0x1000bced0 0x1000bcf88 0x1000aa5cc 0x1000d03e8 0x10006ba24 0x1000cf544 0x1000a5cf8 0x100067580 0x10009194c 0x19549d390 0x195498728 0x19546933c 0x195c63014 0x195c5d770 0x195c5db9c 0x18f2ed42c 0x18f2ecd9c 0x18f2ea9a8 0x18f21ada4 0x190c84074 0x1954ce058 0x10009c684 0x18e22959c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339014 0x18e31a000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e403264 0x18e3fe000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e2ad9c4 0x18e24c000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018dd791b0 0x18dd78000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018dd8f5f0 0x18dd78000 + 95728
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018dd8eef8 0x18dd78000 + 93944
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018dda066c 0x18dd98000 + 34412
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f33ef28 0x18f212000 + 1232680
8   lli                             0x0000000100236124 0x100044000 + 2040100
9   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018e3fd30c 0x18e3f7000 + 25356
10  lli                             0x000000010006c47c 0x100044000 + 164988
11  lli                             0x00000001000be188 0x100044000 + 500104
12  lli                             0x00000001000bd0b0 0x100044000 + 495792
13  lli                             0x00000001000bced0 0x100044000 + 495312
14  lli                             0x00000001000bcf88 0x100044000 + 495496
15  lli                             0x00000001000aa5cc 0x100044000 + 419276
16  lli                             0x00000001000d03e8 0x100044000 + 574440
17  lli                             0x000000010006ba24 0x100044000 + 162340
18  lli                             0x00000001000cf544 0x100044000 + 570692
19  lli                             0x00000001000a5cf8 0x100044000 + 400632
20  lli                             0x0000000100067580 0x100044000 + 144768
21  lli                             0x000000010009194c 0x100044000 + 317772
22  UIKit                           0x000000019549d390 0x195459000 + 279440
23  UIKit                           0x0000000195498728 0x195459000 + 259880
24  UIKit                           0x000000019546933c 0x195459000 + 66364
25  UIKit                           0x0000000195c63014 0x195459000 + 8429588
26  UIKit                           0x0000000195c5d770 0x195459000 + 8406896
27  UIKit                           0x0000000195c5db9c 0x195459000 + 8407964
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ed42c 0x18f212000 + 898092
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ecd9c 0x18f212000 + 896412
30  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ea9a8 0x18f212000 + 887208
31  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
32  GraphicsServices                0x0000000190c84074 0x190c78000 + 49268
33  UIKit                           0x00000001954ce058 0x195459000 + 479320
34  lli                             0x000000010009c684 0x100044000 + 362116
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018e22959c 0x18e225000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339a88 0x18e31a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3ff1a4 0x18e3fe000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x000000018fd34d74 0x18fd28000 + 52596
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fd55b44 0x18fd28000 + 187204
7   UIKit                           0x0000000195e586a8 0x195459000 + 10483368
8   Foundation                      0x000000018fe322d8 0x18fd28000 + 1090264
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 4 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a8f1e540 0x1a8eaa000 + 476480
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a8f44814 0x1a8eaa000 + 632852
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e338e1c 0x18e31a000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e400814 0x18e3fe000 + 10260
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018dd29ac8 0x18dd22000 + 31432
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc6f94 0x19320d000 + 10198932
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc6f08 0x19320d000 + 10198792
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc6de8 0x19320d000 + 10198504
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193bc7098 0x19320d000 + 10199192
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFNetwork.CustomProtocols
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fb82f50 0x18f945000 + 2350928
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa26df4 0x18f945000 + 925172
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fe322d8 0x18fd28000 + 1090264
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e339a88 0x18e31a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fefd0 0x18e3fe000 + 4048
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecac 0x18e3fe000 + 3244

Thread 9 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   AudioToolbox                    0x000000019218de00 0x1920ea000 + 671232
3   AudioToolbox                    0x000000019219205c 0x1920ea000 + 688220
4   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001924724bc 0x1920ea000 + 3703996
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   AudioToolbox                    0x000000019229e9fc 0x1920ea000 + 1788412
6   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001924724bc 0x1920ea000 + 3703996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 12 name:  WebThread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b224 0x18e31a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e31b09c 0x18e31a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2ece90 0x18f212000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f2eaae4 0x18f212000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f21ada4 0x18f212000 + 36260
5   WebCore                         0x0000000193ee5608 0x193ea2000 + 275976
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3feca8 0x18e3fe000 + 3240

Thread 15 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e338e1c 0x18e31a000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e400814 0x18e3fe000 + 10260
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019321a8b4 0x19320d000 + 55476
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193badb18 0x19320d000 + 10095384
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x00000001951551b0 0x1950c1000 + 606640
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x0000000195157e48 0x1950c1000 + 618056
6   WebKitLegacy                    0x0000000195157450 0x1950c1000 + 615504
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193216e88 0x19320d000 + 40584
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193216d98 0x19320d000 + 40344
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40168c 0x18e3fe000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e40159c 0x18e3fe000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e3fecb4 0x18e3fe000 + 3252

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702ee5b1
    x4: 0x000000018dd938a7   x5: 0x000000016fdb7f70   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000002
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000016fdb79e0  x11: 0x0000000000000031
   x12: 0x0000030000000403  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000040000000400  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000018ddbee2c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b4d97b40  x21: 0x000000016fdb7f70  x22: 0x000000017000a3a0  x23: 0x0000000100369539
   x24: 0x0000000139ddce40  x25: 0x0000000195fa6d1c  x26: 0x0000000000000170  x27: 0x000000010051d000
   x28: 0x0000000000000150   fp: 0x000000016fdb7ed0   lr: 0x000000018e403264
    sp: 0x000000016fdb7eb0   pc: 0x000000018e339014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

They say that

> Your app crashes on iPhone and iPad running iOS 10.3.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we tap the Settings button on the main menu.

But I have tried on my iPhone running 10.3.2 iOS, and unable to reproduce it. It looks like a null pointer exception to me. But I am not quite sure.

Comment: you need re-simbolicate your crash logs first to see anything

Comment: it's copied from app review guys. I am not able to reproduce. I suspect that it only happens when distribution signed.

Comment: ok, but you need to resimbolicate them to see why is crashing your app

Comment: Until you symbolicate (not resimbolicate) the crash reports and see which line of code is causing the problem, and post relevant code, no one here can help you.

Comment: how do i symbolicate the crash report that's not generated from my xcode?

Comment: There are countless existing discussions on symbolicating crash reports. Please do some searching.

Comment: Apple should have sent the crash reports as attachments in the review rejection. You can use these in step 5 of [this process](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATEWITHXCODE) in order to symbolicate them.